# Why is my ng-hide / show not working with my ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I want to show the elements that contain displayCategory.name with the ng-click above it, but it's not working as expected.

```
.divider-row
      .row-border(ng-hide="showMe")
        .row.row-format
          .col-xs-12.top-label
            Find where you stand
        %hr.profile
        .row.labelRow
          .col-xs-12
            %ul
              %li(ng-repeat='category in service.categories')
                .clear.btn.Category(ng-click='thisCategory(category) ; showMe = true') {{category.name}}

      .divider-row
      .row-border(ng-show="showMe")
        .row.row-format
          .col-sm-12.col-md-12.top-label.nopadLeft
            What do you think about {{displayCategory.name}}
```

Comment: You mixed css with angular. AngularJS works only on HTML.

Comment: No, this is a html template (haml)

Comment: jade is processed on server side why mixing with client side framework?

Comment: well, to be precise, this is haml (very similar to jade). But, you can actually run jade on client side: http://timnew.me/blog/2014/05/26/use-jade-as-client-side-template-engine/

Comment: However, the template is not the root of my concern.

Comment: @NoobSter ok I was not knowing that.

Comment: Post html for client side problems. We shouldn't have to parse your server templating language and html is what the browser uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot run your code to verify, but I think the problem is that the binding property `showMe` should be replaced with some object like `status.showMe`.

For example, define `$scope.status = { showMe: false};` outside the `ng-repeat` (in your controller maybe).

Please check a working demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jx854d3y/1/

---

**Explanations:**

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each item. The child scope prototypical inherits from the parent scope. In your case, the primitive `showMe` is assigned to the child scope. While you use it **outside** the `ng-repeat`, where it tries to get the value from the parent scope, which is `undefined`. That is why it is not working.

Basic rule is: always use `Object`, instead of primitive types, for binding.

For more details, please refer to: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 2):

I dropped your haml into a converter and this is what it spat out (clearly incorrect):

```
<div class="divider-row">
  <div class="row-border">(ng-hide="showMe")
    <div class="row row-format">
      <div class="col-xs-12 top-label">
        Find where you stand
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="profile"/>
    <div class="row labelRow">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul>
          <li>(ng-repeat='category in service.categories')
            <div class="clear btn Category">(ng-click='thisCategory(category) ; showMe = true') {{category.name}}</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divider-row"></div>
  <div class="row-border">(ng-show="showMe")
    <div class="row row-format">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 top-label nopadLeft">
        What do you think about {{displayCategory.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So after some quick googling I found that you should be writing it like this:

```
.divider-row
  .row-border{"ng-hide" => "showMe"}
    .row.row-format
      .col-xs-12.top-label
        Find where you stand...
```

As that will convert to what you need:

```
<div class="divider-row">
  <div class="row-border" ng-hide="showMe">
    <div class="row row-format">
      <div class="col-xs-12 top-label">
        Find where you stand
```

Using curly braces instead of round ones for attributes

Comment: This is angular on rails. You can use either the parens or the mustache. I did try your solution just to verify, but it still did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you paste the output you get? "not working as expected" is very vague.